# Is there a plugin for syntax highlight for assembly MIPS?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, filetype-assembly

I haven't been able to find any syntax highlighting for MIPS assembly language. I have [CoC](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim) installed, but I don't think it supports MIPS. Is there any other plugin that I could use for basic syntax highlighting and auto-completion?

I am currently using neovim v0.4.4

Comment: Google "vim mips" and first 4 or 5 results are for vim syntax highlighting for MIPS.

Comment: Right, I have tried a few of those and they didn't work in neovim. Can you please enlighten me on how they are configured?

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not really helpful. How doesn't it work? Regardless, most of the time it can be as simple as "put {filetype}.vim in your `$HOME/.vim/syntax` folder" (or equivalent). In your case `mips.vim`. Like it says under Installation here: https://github.com/harenome/vim-mipssyntax

Comment: I can't think of any particular reason why neovim wouldn't be able to handle any syntax file. That's a fundamental compatibility area, AFAIK.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 1):

Sure. I built one for my class last semester: [benknoble/vim-mips](https://github.com/benknoble/vim-mips)

You get syntax highlighting, include and define searches, and comment niceties out-of-the-box. Support for ALE/`:make` is a goal but hasn’t been implemented yet.